# Bundle Product Options as thumbnails or swatches - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have a sofa
It is a frame + 3 cushions that we sell as a set.
We have cushions in colors red green and yellow.
What I want to do is 
Create a bundle that has 
Option 1 - Frame
                  Products FRAMESKU - Qty 1
Option 2 Cushion
Products
Green-cushion Qty 3
Yellow-cushion qty 3
red-cushion qty 3

BUT
Instead of word choices for colors, I want to show a color swatch.
AND
Instead of no image, I want to flip the main image based on the option chosen. So when someone chooses a green cushion, a sofa frame with green cushions shows up.

I can create a bundle  without the images now (with only words, and with only the main image) - but I need to show customers the actual color of the bundle product as a swatch and if possible change the main image to match.

I want to show the thumbnails/swatches on the right block, below the price.

Why am I doing this? Because the Bundle Product allows me to ship separately and therefore lists out the components. I can then use the skus at a component level for tranfer to our accounting system (QUickbooks) as well as creating very simplified packing lists that people do not need to translate from a dynamic sku to component parts.

Is this possible? I think it should be but I would like some help.  I am open to some consulting help.

Thanks very much in advance.
Sam

Comment: Why don't you use configurable product with color swatch in this case ?

Comment: Because in inventory control I am counting CUSHIONS and FRAMES. If there is a way to take a sku and split it into two other skus for inventory control, I could use a configurable product. In a config product the associated simple product would have to be a simple product which is a frame + cushions. This means that I have to have all permutations of colors and frames. I actually have 6 frame sizes and 27 colors.

Comment: You can try this extension http://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-advanced-product-options-suite.html. Create Sofa as simple product with two custom option Frame and Cushions

Comment: Good reverse logic idea. Will try and get back to you.  I believe it might work for sofa, but it will not work if I put sofa in another set with another chair and coffee table. Good idea though.